# Connecting MS Access Web Database Tables and Queries

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I have created MS Web Access Database (2010) and hosted in SharePoint 2010. I would like to create reports in SharePoint using MS Web Access Database Tables; possibly using SSRS.

I'm able to develop reports in SSRS by using workspace lists; but don't know how to connect with MS Web Access Database tables and queries to create SSRS reports. Any help?

Thanks in advance.